# how to remove tuples with similar content by different orders in SPARQL

Tags: tuples, sparql, protege, rdflib

I have a query returning a couple of variable, `?a` and `?b`. The problem is that the results contain, for instance, `10, 15`, and `15, 10`. I need only one of these. How can I check if the tuple already exists?

My query is messy but looks like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?a  ?b
WHERE { ?a   rno:is_extent_of  ?x1
          ;  rno:is_extent_of  ?x2
      . ?b   rno:is_extent_of  ?x3
          ;  rno:is_extent_of  ?x4
      . ?x1  rno:is_part_of    ?d
      . ?x3  rno:is_part_of    ?d
      . ?d   a                 rno:detailed_partition
      . ?x2  rno:is_part_of    ?r
      . ?x4  rno:is_part_of    ?r
      . ?r   a                 rno:Roundabout
      .  FILTER ( ?x1 != ?x2 
               && ?x1 != ?x3
               && ?x1 != ?x4 )
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use some feature of ?a annd ?b to order them.  For example, if they are always URIs:

```
FILTER ( str(?a)  < str(?b) )
```